# Userscript with xcode4

Tags: xcode4, userscripts, xcode3to4

Does anybody knows how to use xcode3 userscripts in xcode4 ?

There was this great script which allowed you to select a variable and automatically generate property/synthetise/dealloc code :

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html

Do you have any idea how to do this in xcode4 ?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working a little while ago. Abstracted it out into a re-usable processor for Xcode 3 scripts.  Find it at https://github.com/heardrwt/Xcode4UserScripts

Answer (score 1):

It's gone as far as I can see. We'll probably have to use an external script system that takes text from the clipboard, processes it and then puts it back.

Comment: That's what i thought, do you have some clue about how to write that external script system : what tool could do that, some tutorial maybe ? Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do that with Xcode4 :

https://github.com/CraigWilliams/property_synthesize_dealloc